# How to link an image from a global path

Tags: webpack

I need to link an image from a "global" path, a path not inside the application served by webpack. I have done something like :

```
<img src="/users/name/home/Desktop/test.svg"/>
```

,but I cannot see the image and if a take a look at the img element with inspector I see that the path is this:

```
http://localhost:8080/users/name/home/Desktop/test.svg
```

I think the reason is that all this images are served by webpack but I haven't any idea how to change this behaviour.
Here my webpack dev configuration file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const redis = require('redis')

// Config directories
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const OUTPUT_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

// Any directories you will be adding code/files into, need to be added to this array so webpack will pick them up
const defaultInclude = [SRC_DIR];

module.exports = {
  entry: SRC_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: OUTPUT_DIR,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'hiredis': path.join(__dirname, 'aliases/hiredis.js')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' },
              { loader: 'css-loader' }],
        include: defaultInclude
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
        include: defaultInclude
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }],
        include: defaultInclude
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=font/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]'}],
        include: defaultInclude
      }
    ]
  },
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: OUTPUT_DIR,
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      chunks: false,
      children: false
    },
    setup() {
      spawn(
        'electron',
        ['.'],
        { shell: true, env: process.env, stdio: 'inherit' }
      )
      .on('close', code => process.exit(0))
      .on('error', spawnError => console.error(spawnError));
    }
  }
};
```

Thanks

Paolo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack is not copying images to dist folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704770/webpack-is-not-copying-images-to-dist-folder)

Comment: No, is a different question, anyway thanks