# Webpack is not copying images to dist folder

Tags: html, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm starting with webpack, but I'm really new on this and I'm stuck right now.
My project copies my fonts correctly but not images. Now the only way I am able to make it work is by copying my images manually to the `dist/img` folder.

This is my config:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
entry: './src/app.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    // publicPath:  '/dist',
},
module: {
    rules:[
        {
        test:/\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: ["css-loader?sourceMap","resolve-url-loader","sass-loader?sourceMap"],
            // publicPath: '/dist'
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$/,
            use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }  
                  }]
            // loader: 'file-loader?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
            use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'img/',
                        publicPath:'img/'
                    }  
                  }]
        }
    ]
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 8000,
    stats: "errors-only",
    open: true
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Project',
        hash:true,
        template: './src/index.html'
    })
]
}
```

I've tried several configurations but no solution. I also searched here for any solution but without success.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your images are only referenced in HTML files as `<img>` tags, webpack by default won't pick them up because it doesn't parse HTML. You have at least 2 choices:

1. Use [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to copy the files to wherever you want, this at least removes the "manual" part you mention
2. Move your images references to styles, where webpack can pick them up via the scss loader you are using. For example

   ```
   background-image: url("img/foo.png");
   ```

Comment: Ah ok thanks!
I´m trying now with CopyWebpackPlugin and it works great!

Comment: great! Please accept this answer if it is working for you.

Comment: i'm try to use your solution but i have problem

Comment: new CopyPlugin([
            { from: './img/*', to: 'img', force: true},
          ])

Comment: It works, but copy files without image optmizations

Answer (score 3):

There is also option import image trough JavaScript.

```
import '../img/image.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I didn't know that the file-loader only copies the images if you run a build, and doesn't do anything while using webpack-dev-server. My solution was just:

```
$ npx webpack
```